# Controlling C++ compiler for Dart FFI via Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, dart, ffi

Friends

I am using a C++ routine called using FFI from Dart/Flutter on iOS.  i am getting disappointing  results.

I followed [these instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios/c-interop), which basically had me dropping C++ files into the Xcode file structure.

I would like to know:

- what C++ compiler I am using (I am assuming clang, but assumptions....)
- How I can pass parameters to that compiler
- How I can examine the output of the C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

> what C++ compiler I am using (I am assuming clang, but assumptions....)

> How I can pass parameters to that compiler

In Xcode Runner-> Build Settings there are the "Apple Clang" configuration options

> How I can examine the output of the C++ compiler

That I still do not know